# If I reroll a hero-specific loot chest, will the reroll still include the hero related loot?

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

From patch note :

```
Hero Level Progression Rewards
```

Hero progression rewards have also received significant changes, and can be earned at the following milestones:

- Hero level 5: Hero Portrait
- Hero level 15: Master Hero Portrait
- Every 5 Hero levels: 500 Gold
- Every 10 Hero levels: Hero-specific Loot Chest

**Hero-specific Loot Chests are guaranteed to drop at least one item that’s usable by the Hero who earned it.**

What if I reroll one of those chest ? Will the Hero-specific reward be rerolled too ?
Outcome will be :
A/ Another hero specific reward ?
B/ Anything else ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, just like if you re-roll a Rare chest you're guaranteed to get at least one Rare item from the chest.  Same with Epic and Veteran chests too.

Just keep in mind that "hero-specific" loot also includes that hero's emoji packs, sprays, and voice lines, so you won't necessarily get a skin out of your chest.

Comment: Actually, one of my friends rerolled a character-specific chest twice.  The first re-roll didn't have a character specific re-roll while the second did.

Comment: A reroll should just generate a new chest of the same type.  Maybe your friend won something hero-specific but trivial (like the hero's emoji pack) or something they already had and saw the shard banner?

Comment: So if I understand, reroll forfait the hero-specific quality of that chest and turn it into any other chest ?

Comment: @Okami No, it creates a new hero-specific chest for your hero.

Comment: @Powerlord if true that is a bug and should be reported